# Convert PDF String into downloadable format

Tags: reactjs

Aim : I have a PDF string , I am trying to download it as a PDF document once i click download button. Note - I am getting this PDF string from Blob (I am passing this string from Server to Client Side)

using the below code to convert the PDF File from blob to PDF String-

```
    const downloadBlobToString = async (containerClient: any, blobName: any) => {
  const blobClient = await containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
  const downloadResponse = await blobClient.download(0);
  const downloaded = await streamToBuffer(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody);
  return downloaded.toString();
};
```

Problem Statement - The file is getting downloaded but getting error as "Failed to load document" once i try to open it.

PDF String -

```
%PDF-1.7 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [6 0 R ] /Count 1 /Resources << /ProcSet 4 0 R /Font << /F1 8 0 R /F2 9 0 R >> >> /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5 0 obj << /Producer (��dompdf 1.0.2 + CPDF) /CreationDate (D:20221216202946+00'00') /ModDate (D:20221216202946+00'00') /Title (��Untitled Spreadsheet) /Author (��Unknown Creator) >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000] /Parent 3 0 R /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 822 >> stream x����N�@��y��zil��mn�Ҫ��P��—��:����Q; ;�j{�-��&3��;�<QBJ ���zb�0���Z��V���װ��b"w����>b�r�N����M�oQ�J4��%�R-�w�Y!���j���>*X#*�����8��x�J(�`:��4(��������E�z|s �S8�N:)Ф���J4ʼ����U#�Lk��f#ccS���P�g�E�w��];��gp���sY g|��Zho1x��m�7M��+�YGww��28~f���*X|�.��()��)�ǡ��;�҃O�=��t-�N����� V���/�3����j�;�C{a����@�������Dx>���n8��nS����;ٔ9"�%G�Ғ#8m�kCqY � qi�޸J(�+�A�C���+��O-A�%r�� ݵ!� �+x�^���9�<\�^�ۛ�ͪ�tޟ �=�d���;��>�Tً?`��I�ptΨp��GۺH��B��z@���z����a=��6�Ġ�hQw�+���@a��ӦK6�m@qC�$.��W�Mzp�J���P�`��A�hC�UJ(�y�0|����_=��_m[�>�#���r��E��=T���!v�J �������`���v�:}s�Bo��絨R�P!�z�Q)�g��8�w��~�PΔ)%@��H�z52&n�p"�0'*p�}��]d�8��.����g�q'���=v��J���࿽��j�3Y.�,����Qgn=�xq?���߁I'U �GD�����݀�� endstream endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F2 /BaseFont /Times-Roman /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 10 0 obj [6 0 R /Fit] endobj xref 0 11 0000000000 65535 f 0000000009 00000 n 0000000074 00000 n 0000000120 00000 n 0000000284 00000 n 0000000313 00000 n 0000000557 00000 n 0000000660 00000 n 0000001554 00000 n 0000001661 00000 n 0000001770 00000 n trailer << /Size 11 /Root 1 0 R /Info 5 0 R /ID[<73c60b8a58a461322f732d1e85a77dd1><73c60b8a58a461322f732d1e85a77dd1>] >> startxref 1799 %%EOF
```

Solution Tried -

```
const downloadPDF01 = (data: any) => {
console.log(data);
const binaryString = window.atob(data);
const binaryLen = binaryString.length;
const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
for (let i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
  const ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  bytes[i] = ascii;
}
const blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'downloadedPdf';
link.click();
```

};

Even tried the below solution -

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'downloadedfile.pdf'); //or any other extension
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank You,

Comment: @K J , Do you have any sample code as how to convert PDF string to Base64 , I tried converting using atob but it works only on client side , There is some other solution where i have to install some external base64 encoder and decoder. Is there any way we can convert to base64 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a known good PDF.   I took your string, saved it as a PDF and received errors when trying to open it.

Comment: This is the PDF string which i am reading from the blob , And it is opening there.